# force sudo to forget password immediately after exit everytime

Tags: login, sudo, sudoers

If I execute `sudo su`, I am asked for my password ( `[sudo] password for ...` )

After do some stuff, I can leave this root mode with `exit`.

If I execute again `sudo su`, I will not be asked for a password again. (Only if a few minutes have passed)

I can immediately let it forget the password with `sudo -k` or `sudo -K` but how can I disable it completely for all users or better: How can I modify the timer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run **sudo visudo** and on the line

```
Defaults env_reset
```

add (separate it with a comma)

```
timestamp_timeout=0
```

The line should then look like this:

> Defaults env_reset,timestamp_timeout=0

From now on sudo should ask for password every time for any user.

EDIT: You can of course set the timeout to any value.